# Mac OS X: master-detail interface and Cocoa Bindings

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, master-detail, nsviewcontroller

I have a master-detail interface. In the "master part" I show a list of people, in the "detail part" I show the detail of the selected person, including a list of things that the person has:

```
 master part               detail part
   |                           |
   v                           v
+--------------------+------------------------+
| Person1            | Detail of Person2      |
| Person2 (selected) |                        |
| Person3            | Thing1 of person2      |
| Person4            | Thing2 of person2      |
| Person5            | Thing3 of person2      |
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

People and things are placed in a Core Data-managed data model.

The "master part" is managed in the NSWindowController in which I have a NSArrayController connected, through Cocoa Bindings, to my people entities.

The "detail part" is managed in a separated NSViewController.

From this detail-NSViewController it is possible to use Cocoa Bindings to access to the selected person in the master part? It is possible to do that from Interface Builder?

Comment: Solved thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368225/binding-selection-across-multiple-view-controllers-in-a-single-window-interface

Comment: Then post that as an answer and mark it accepted to clean up after yourself so people don't keep looking at an open question. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that I could answer myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to this post: [Binding selection across multiple view controllers in a single window interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368225/binding-selection-across-multiple-view-controllers-in-a-single-window-interface)